# Did Melchizedek worship the same God as Abram?

Tags: genesis, abraham, names-of-god, melchizedek

In [Genesis 14:18](http://biblehub.com/genesis/14-18.htm), there is a man, [Melchizedek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melchizedek), who was a priest of the Most High God:

> Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine. (Now he was the priest of the **Most High God**.) (NET)

A few verses later, in [Genesis 14:22](http://biblehub.com/genesis/14-18.htm):

> But Abram replied to the king of Sodom, "I raise my hand to the **LORD**, the **Most High God**, Creator of heaven and earth, ... (NET)

So did Melchizedek worship the same God as Abram?

Comment: As it stands, there are a great variety of answers to this question. I highly suggest narrowing down the scope of answers you expect to see.

Answer (score 3):

Good question! Firstly, the name they used is the same. In Hebrew Most High God is "elyon" and it's used in both verses you refer to.

Melchizedek is a really interesting character. In Psalms 110: 4 there is a bit where it says "you are a priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek". But who is this "priest forever"? The writer of Hebrews gives the answer, at 5:5,6 and I encourage you to read that book (it's in the New Testament) to clarify this answer. In short, the forever priest is Jesus of Nazareth. His God is the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob (Matthew 22:32 and elsewhere). And he is the "priest in the order of Melchizedek". So the God of Abraham and the God of Melchizedek is surely the same.